# Cannot find module './auth.service' in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use Angular Guards, to protect my pages from access without being authenticated.

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot , Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router) { }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        if(this.authService.isAuth) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }   
    }
}
```

the problem is that I can not import the module auth.service. it show me this error ( cannot find module './auth.service'. any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you show us you project tree? Nobody can give you an answer, because you ask "Where from should I import custom file?" when we don't know where you created it and where you placed it.

Comment: just discovered that my service file was missing :(, thank you @Nikita . Should i delete this dumb question ?

Comment: Yeah, this site not for such kind of questions, heh.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check the path that **stores** the `AuthService`. The easiest ways is to erase whatever inside the quotation mark and place a `../` then your IDE will suggest you the path to your `AuthService`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the file is actually there! Also, try using Webstorm or Eclipse, or any kind of IDE to see the exact problems in the code. Sometimes the IDE even fixes the errors for you!